# JSON parsing error

Tags: iphone

I am trying to parse some JSON. I've passed a constant key value and a string - butI'm receivng 16 objects in the `statuses` array and 20 objects in `ststuses1`.

Are any of the parsing steps wrong?

I have included the code for the JSON parser.

Thanks in advance.

```
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];

 NSString *urlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.shiki.com/api/serch?key=%@&q=%@",apiKey, string];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
 NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSMutableArray *statuses = nil;
 statuses = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

 NSMutableArray *statuses0 = [[statuses valueForKey:@"offers"] valueForKey:@"offer"];
 NSLog(@"Array Contents: %@", statuses0);
```

Comment: Does this even compile?  You declared `statuses` 3 times when it should only be declared once.  Also, I don't see a `statuses1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that's not the only syntax-error in your code...

Please define *statuses* and *ststuses1*. I can only see *statuses* (redefined 2 times) and *statuses0*. Also please post a sample of the json-data you're parsing so I can take a look at it.